# Jquery ajax call using json vb.net

Tags: jquery, ajax, call

After making ajax call using Jquery to the vb.net server side code, I need to make whole page to reload on the success of AJAX call.

This is my client side AJAX call..

$("#ButtonSave").click(function () {

```
//convert gridview to JSON
var jsonData = new Array();
$.map($("table[id*=Gridview1] tr"), function (item, index) {
    if ($(item).find("input[type=text]").length > 0) {
        jsonData[index] = new Object();
        jsonData[index].charge = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtCharge]").val();
        jsonData[index].produce = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtProduce]").val();         
        jsonData[index].weight = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtWeight]").val();
        jsonData[index].feet = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtFeet]").val();
        jsonData[index].orderNumber = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtOrderNumber]").val(); 
        jsonData[index].comments = $(item).find("input[type=text][id*=txtComments]").val();
    }
});

var jsonStringData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: "Correction.aspx",
    type: "POST",
    timeout: 10000,
    data: "jsonData=" + jsonStringData
})
.error(function () {
    alert('Error');
})
.success(function (data) {
    alert('Success');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong ajax call You cannot assign it into variable and you are sending data incorrectly

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: "Correction.aspx",
    type: "POST",
    timeout: 10000,
    data: "jsonData=" + jsonStringData
})
.error(function () {
    alert('Error');
})
.success(function (data) {
    alert('Success');
});
```

use this

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "Correction.aspx",
    type: "POST",
    timeout: 10000,
    data: {jsonData: jsonStringData}
})
.error:(function () {
    alert('Error');
})
.success:(function (data) {
   window.location.reload(true);

});
```

Comment: It doesn't help. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user1733547 see the edited answer i want also missing `:` after success

Comment: There is no Error. It is not refreshing the whole page.           Here is the scenario... I have GridView1 and Gridview2 in Correction.aspx. GridView1 is for displaying the data from database. Gridview2 where I am updating or deleting the record. So When I click on any record in GridView1 it is populating in the Gridview2 with the data and after changing some field in Gridview2 I hit the "Save" button and there I am calling above Jquery AJAX call. So once the AJAX call is done I need to load the Correction.aspx page with updated value which display in Gridview1.

Answer (score 0):

or instead of use reload using

```
     window.location.reload(true);
```

you can make hidden button and on success call $("your button").Click();
it's going to refresh your page

```
    $("#<%= btnrefresh.ClientID %>").Click();
```

I am always use this technique and working perfect